# SUM function in Pandas dataframe gives a different total compared to summation in Excel spreadsheet

Tags: python, pandas, excel, dataframe

I am getting different results when I run the sum() function in pandas compared to the totals which show up in Excel. I am pivoting the dataframe in pandas to get different views of the data and check if theres a difference between the totals in pandas and excel.

The complete dataframe ('merged_data') is available as a .csv file here: [https://github.com/yyshastri/NZ-Police-Community-Dataset/blob/7562ae2d9b8c4337d9ad8bd436f5d355826820b0/Merged_Community_Police_Data_v2.xlsx][1]

The code is as below:

```
 # select Auckland and the far North district
TA_data = merged_data[merged_data['TA2018_name'].isin(['Auckland','Far North District'])].copy()
dfp2 = TA_data.pivot_table(index='Year', columns='crime', values='Reported Incidents', aggfunc='sum')
dfp2.head()
```

This is the result of the above code:

| crime | Abduction | Assault | Blackmail | Illegal Use of Motor Vehicle | Illegal Use of Property | Robbery | Sexual Assault | Theft (Other) | Theft From Retail Premises | Theft From a Person | Theft from a Motor Vehicle | Theft of a Motor Vehicle | Unlawful Entry, B&E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Year |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 2018 | 96 | 6095 | 56 | 10548 | 491 | 1202 | 541 | 12831 | 8670 | 573 | 10654 | 52 | 19873 |
| 2019 | 92 | 7042 | 85 | 11014 | 703 | 1213 | 596 | 15893 | 10012 | 670 | 12665 | 42 | 22910 |
| 2020 | 67 | 7135 | 90 | 9335 | 493 | 961 | 661 | 15182 | 11517 | 556 | 8883 | 30 | 18791 |

There is a variance of anywhere between 6 to 200+ between the total from pandas vis-a-vis Excel. For example, the category of "Assault" for 2020 gives 7135 in the df but in Excel it shows 7723.
I might be missing the obvious but would appreciate any pointers.
[1]: https://github.com/yyshastri/NZ-Police-Community-Dataset/blob/7562ae2d9b8c4337d9ad8bd436f5d355826820b0/Merged_Community_Police_Data_v2.xlsx

Comment: How was this Excel file generated? From pandas? Please show code for [mre].

Comment: Thanks for responding but the problem is sorted. Please see my comment to the accepted answer. Was a silly mistake on my part. regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case it wouldve been helpful if you would have also given us the information how you found the Excel Sum.

It turns out that your dfp2 data is right but your formula for the Excel search mustve been wrong.

For Assault 2020 in Auckland/Far North District i get 7135 with your python script and 7135 in Excel.

The used **Excel** formula looks like this:

```
=SUMIFS( C:C; B:B; "Assault";J:J;2020;H:H;{"Auckland";"Far North District"})
```

output [image]which equals to 7135.

Here is also another way in **python** to find 7135 incidents without pivoting the table:

```
merged_data["Reported Incidents"][(merged_data["crime"]=="Assault")&(merged_data["Reported Incidents"]>=1)& (merged_data["Year"]==2020)&(merged_data["TA2018_name"].isin(["Auckland","Far North District"]))].sum()
#output
7135
```

Comment: Many thank for your help.  I had a brain freeze! I went back to Excel after reading your solution and realized that I had forgotten to filter the other districts out in Excel which led to the higher number. Dumb mistake. Appreciate your help.